# Grid case sensitive in the field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I initialize a kendo grid in my project like below:

```
         $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            ...
            columns: [{                    
                field: "One",
                title: "One"
            }, {
                field: "Two",
                title: "Two"
            }, {
                field: "Three",
                title: "Three"
            }]
        });
```

I'm facing the problem of the data in column "One" always return some weird value such as `function(e,t){return this.bind(e,t,!...`. After some investigate, I found out that the data is actually from a function in the kendo.all.min.js:

```
one:function(e,t){return this.bind(e,t,!0)}
```

So is it means that the word "one"(other word like:first, bind also return weird value) is case sensitive in kendo grid and cannot used as the field name? And is there any method that i can use to escape it to make it case insensitive?
Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Can you add a screen shot? Also,can you elaborate where exactly do you see `function(e,t){return this.bind(e,t,!...` and when?

Comment: Please add more information, I could not reproduce that behaviour https://dojo.telerik.com/owulIcUw